# Geometry type error with LineString

Tags: pgadmin-3

I tried to process the following query with PgAdmin III, but it doesn't work and the hint provided doesn't make sense to me :

UPDATE grille_segments_finale
SET shipping_cost = 1000000
WHERE st_intersects(grille_segments_finale.geom::LineString, countries.geom::MultiPolygon) is true ;

And I get:
ERREUR:  le type « linestring » n'existe pas
LINE 6: WHERE st_intersects(grille_segments_finale.geom::LineString,...
                                                         ^

********** Erreur **********

ERREUR: le type « linestring » n'existe pas
État SQL :42704
Caractère : 191

Could you help me please? The geometry "LineString" is the right geometry type of my table ("grille_segments_finale") so I can't really find out where I am wrong...

Comment: I can't explain why, but leave out out the casts and it probably works: `(grille_segments_finale.geom, countries.geom)`

Comment: It didn"t work either, so I decided to use the "Spacial query" tool with QGIS to find which parts of "grille_segments_finale" intersect parts of "countries".

Comment: Edit : I think it didn't worked because I asked to find, for each part of "grille_segments_finale", if it was intersecting one specific part of "countries" (for each part of "countries"). But what I want is to know is, for each part of "grille_segments_finale", if it intersects one part of "countries". 
So maybe it's because of that. The process is running on QGIS and should be over tomorrow so I don't know if I will try to find a new method and to implement it on postgreSQL...

Comment: What do you mean by "It didn't work either"? Did you still get the same error?